# Posterior distribution dependent on two variables make inferences about one

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, posterior

If I have some model for X that depends on $\theta_1, \theta_2$ and has a posterior $P(\theta_1, \theta_2 | x_1, ... x_n)$, how would I make inferences just about $\theta_1$?

What I am thinking so far is just to integrate $P(\theta_1, \theta_2 | x_1,...,x_n)$ over $\theta_2$ to get $P(\theta_1 | x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: That would indeed be the standard approach to obtain the marginal posterior and to make the desired inference.

Comment: You are right in your approach but what is your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the marginal, if tractable, is a good approach. Another, perhaps easier approach is to calculate the full conditional of $\theta_1\: |\: x_1, ..., x_, \theta_2$ and $\theta_2\: |\: x_1, ..., x_, \theta_1$. These are sometimes easier to find analytically. Then you could simply perform Gibbs sampling to find the posterior for $\theta_1$ and make inferences on that. Personally, I try to avoid integrals when possible.